Does OpenReview Automatically Notify All Authors Upon Submission?
I am preparing a submission for the AAAI 2025 Conference via OpenReview, and I have a question about the notification process for co-authors.
When I submit the paper, does OpenReview automatically send a notification email to all co-authors listed on the submission? If not, what steps do I need to take to ensure that all authors are informed about the submission?
I have read through the submission guidelines, and while I understand how to complete the submission, I am not clear on whether or not my co-authors will be notified automatically.
Any insights or experiences with this process would be greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance for your help.

Not an answer but a frame challenge: If you're submitting to a conference and something about the submission process is unclear to you but not specified on the submission site, contact the conference organizers to ask for clarification!

Have you considered forwarding whatever notification you receive to your co-authors via email?  Even if they get notification via other means, it's a nice way to wrap up a submission.  You can even thank your coauthors for their help.

Yes, OpenReview has always sent me an email notification whenever a submission was created by one of my co-authors.
It's difficult to confirm if this is always the case, but having used OpenReview both as an author and a Program Chair, I have not seen any option to disable this, so I assume it's always sent to all authors.

Thank you for the answer. Reading through the submission guideline, I found this: After submission, the system will not automatically send a confirmation of receipt. If you want to receive a confirmation email, please click the paper ID to view the submission, and then click the “Email” button at the top right to send the confirmation to yourself or all the authors. AAAI will contact authors again only if problems are encountered with papers

So this in contrast to the answer given here.  Can I rely on that then?

@Luise. You should trust the answer you found on your own, direct from the source
